# Having hard time trying to coppy-paste some questions from the internet to my IDE(pycharm).Some mathematic symbols are messed up

Tags: python, pycharm

just started working on my quiz application using python and it has to do with maths(True-False) questions.So whenever i try to copy-paste a question from the internet to my questions array some characters are really messed up.Can anyone help me solve this please? i have searched a lot for a solution but didn't get an answer so far.(I am using Pycharm)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't tell what, you don't tell how i.e. with which code, you don't tell messed up in which way... Sorry, could you please try to imagine yourself into the situation of people who are not you for a Moment, i.e. who don't have your ideas, wishes, current projects, problems and way of thinkings? Great. Now please try again, maybe considering [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are space/tab conversion errors that occur when copy/pasting from a web source.

If that is the problem you're having in pycharm, just highlight the code that was copied > Edit > Convert Indents.

If this is not what you needed, please edit your question to include the code block containing the "really messed up characters" that you are seeing in pycharm. I'll try to see what's happening there.